# changing boolean fields in several structs simultaneously in specman

Tags: specman

I want to change one field that is defined in several classes in my specman env  (currently these fields are global variables in different classes). I want to have the option to change these fields in the middle of test run, and I want to change all of them simultaneously. Since I don't want to access every class and change locally, I thought of using pointers instead of globals. Does anyone know a way to do it in specman? or maybe another solution?

This is for an environment with many classes, and accessing each one takes a lot of coding and run time

Answer (score 0):

Can static field solve your problem? All the instances will see the same value.

```
struct my_s {
    static b: bool;
};
```

An alternative can be a wrapper to bool: all the relevant instances will reference the same wrapper, and once the value inside changes, all of them will see the change:

```
struct bool_wrapper {
    value: bool;
};
struct my_s {
    b: bool_wrapper;
};
```

There is no such thing as a pointer to a value of primitive type in 'e'.

Comment: In a UVM-e context, all classes should reference the same environment configuration struct, of which the suggested wrapper is probably the minimal solution.

Comment: I used this solution with a small change: I realized that It's better for me to use a list of bool. So actually I didn't need a wrapper - the "list of bool" type can get a pointer.
It may be generally easier - instead of wrapping with a new struct, turn the boolean into list of bool with one list member, and create pointers.
Thanks for the help!